# how can i use my executable_jar on ubuntu

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, apache-spark, jar

I have created a spark application on eclipse then I used maven to build and package it, because my OS is windows, I had to add this line to my code to be able to run it on windows:

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop\\");
```

But now and because I want to access to a cluster, I have to use Ubuntu, and I want to use my jar, but I know that that line will cause an error because this path doesn't exist on Ubuntu, so I ask any suggestion to fix this easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while running jar you can specify properties

```
java -Dhadoop.home.dir=/var/hadoop -jar spark.jar
```

for that you may have to remove that line and you can give the hadoop home on run time

Comment: what does it mean -D?

Comment: i use this path because it contains winutils.exe that allows to run spark on windows, but if i run it on ubuntu i don't need this line. and when i run the jar i use spark submit command ((\bin\spark-submit --class myapp.Main --master local[*] file:///C:\Users\pc\Desktop\eclipse\myapp\target\myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar)) so, is it possible to give the hadoop home at run time??

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the Hadoop installation directory outside of your app with a system variable or system property. You can do this in several different ways. For example:

1. Use the `java -D` option.
2. Set a `HADOOP_HOME` system variable in `.bashrc` and read it in your app. (Under Windows, you can set the system variable in the Control Panel or `autoexec.bat`.)